# Setting ProcessPriorityClass for a file having manifest requireAdministrator gives Access denied error in Windows 8

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, process, manifest

In a windows 8 pc my below code gives error "Access denied" for the line which sets priority for process. The WindowsApplication1.exe is having manifest with `level="requireAdministrator"` .

I tried same below code for WindowsApplication1.exe having manifest as `level="asInvoker"` and it worked without error and priority has changed . The user of windows 8 has administrative permission. If I don't set Priority then process starts properly. So error is only when manifest of the file is `requireAdministrator` and in windows 8 pc. The same thing works properly in windows XP PC. So why setting Process priority for a exe having requireAdministrator gives error and how it can be solved.
Note: If I click and open the same exe then it works. Also right click run as administrator also works without any error

```
 Dim app As New Process()
 app.StartInfo.FileName = "WindowsApplication1.exe"
 app.Start()
 app.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal
```